# Access violation writing location 0x00000000 pointers in recursive function

Tags: c, pointers, recursion, matrix, memory-management

This is my code calculating the determinant of a Matrix of complex numbers. I have to define matrices like this(double pointer) because I am working with a really old project with C.(dont ask why)

```
int i, j, k, c1, c2;


typedef struct {
    double re;
    double im;
} cmplx;


cmplx** Create2DMatrixCmplx(int d1, int d2)
{
    cmplx **matCC = (cmplx**)malloc(d1 * sizeof(cmplx*));

    for (i = 0; i < d1; i++)
        matCC[i] = ((cmplx*)malloc(d2 * sizeof(cmplx)));

    if ( matCC == NULL )
    {
        printf("Error: out of memory.\n");
        return;
    }
    return matCC;
}



void matrixCAssign(cmplx** a1, cmplx** a2, int l1, int l2)
{
    for (i = 0; i < l1; i++)
        for (j = 0; j < l2; j++)    
            a1[i][j] = a2[i][j];
}


cmplx determinantC(cmplx **A, int len)
{
    cmplx det, temp;
    cmplx** Matrix =  Create2DMatrixCmplx(len, len);
    cmplx** Minor =  Create2DMatrixCmplx(len, len);
    matrixCAssign( Matrix, A, len, len );

    if(len == 1)
    {
        det = Matrix[0][0];
    }
    else if(len == 2)
    {
        det = (Matrix[0][0] * Matrix[1][1]) - (Matrix[0][1] * Matrix[1][0]));
    }
    else
    {
        for(i = 0 ; i < len ; i++)
        {
            c1 = 0, c2 = 0;
            for(j = 0 ; j < len ; j++)
            {
                for(k = 0 ; k < len ; k++)
                {
                    if(j != 0 && k != i)
                    {
                        Minor[c1][c2] = Matrix[j][k];
                        c2++;
                        if( c2 > len-2 )
                        {
                            c1++;
                            c2=0;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            temp = determinantC(Minor,len-1);
            det +=  ( Matrix[0][i] * temp) * O;

            O = -1 * O;
        }
    }

    return det;
}

main()
{
    cmplx **A= Create2DMatrixCmplx(1024, 1024);
    // set data to A
    cmplx det = determinantC( A, 1024 );
}
```

I get Writing Access error in this line:

> Minor[c1][c2] = Matrix[j][k];

when the error happen, the values are:

> c1=337,    c2=338,    len=974,

"Minor" dimentions are len*len in each iteration and c1, c2 values are smaller.

So I guess the problem must be with pointers. I am making a new instance of "cmplx** Matrix" in each iteration but I am calling the function with the pointer type. Do I get a new instance of the object when I call it with pointer? If so why is it no problem in iterations before? Value of len at the begining is 1024.

Can somebody help me find the problem? I can not see it.

Comment: That probably means that `Minor` is `NULL`, probably because `Create2DMatrixCmplx(len, len)` returned `NULL`. You need to debug this with your debugger. There is not enough code here, we can't help much more. You don't know how to use your debugger? Well, then it's the perfect moment to start learning. BTW: you probbaly need to free the matrice instances `Matrix` and `Minor` after each iteration.

Comment: @MichaelWalz Minor is not empty. I am sure. And I know how to debug. There problem must be something else

Comment: Without [MCVE] we can't do much.

Comment: @MichaelWalz what is needed here?  Create2DMatrixCmplx(len, len)?

Comment: `Matrix = A;` probably doesn't do what you think it does. It's only copying a pointer, not the matrix contents.

Comment: @Mary a [mcve] is needed here.

Comment: Even without an [mcve], there are at least three problems with the code: (1) The memory allocated by the two calls to `Create2DMatrixCmplx` is never freed (do you have a function that frees a 2D matrix?); (2) The line `Matrix = A;` overwrites the pointer to one of the matrices allocated by `Create2DMatrixCmplx` (you probably need to call a function to copy the matrix contents of `A` to `Matrix` instead); (3) the variable `int c[100];` is never used, and quite large for a recursive function (but perhaps the compiler will be kind to you and not allocate any space for it).

Comment: @IanAbbott (1) I take care of Matrix "A" after this function, but I am using "Minor" and "Matrix" here. I am not sure when I can free them. I was doing it right before the "return" but then I thought maybe this is causing my problem and removed it (2) I did add a function to copy the content. but I have error in "Writing" not "Reading" (3) Thanks for the Tip. removed it.

Comment: @IanAbbott I edited the question.

Comment: Where are the variables `c1`, `c2`, `O` and `l` defined? Should `l-1` in the recursive call to `determinantC` be `len-1`?

Comment: It's probably also worth mentioning that this algorithm is completely impractical for large matrices. You should probably find the determinant by Gaussian elimination instead.